# Regex for first page

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Regex for first page?
Everything up to page break \f

This only finds the last line of first page
"end of page one"

I need all 4 lines
"first page"
"second line"
"search string"
"end of page one"

adding \s did not fix it for me
[\s|S] just blows through the \f and finds everything

```
string input = "first page" + Environment.NewLine +
               "second line" + Environment.NewLine +
               "search string" + Environment.NewLine +
               "end of page one\f" +
               "second page" + Environment.NewLine +
               "second line" + Environment.NewLine +
               "search string" + Environment.NewLine +
               "end of page two\f";
public string Input { get { return input; }}
public string FirstPage
{
    get
    {
        //@"((.*)\f)\1(<SEARCH STRING GOES HERE>)"); this is what in the end I need to do
        string pattern = @"(.*)\f";
        Match  match = Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);
        if (match != null)
        {
            return match.Value;
        }
        else
            return "noot found";    
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the question?

Comment: see ? mark.   Regex for first page?

Comment: what is that? please put some input expected output..

Comment: @rock321987 The expected output is the 4 lines of the first page

Comment: your regex is greedy..use `(.*?)\f` instead to make it lazy..

Comment: @rock321987 Thanks, tired that but (.*?)\f did not fix it.  I would think if greedy was the problem it would not find the last line.

Comment: @rock321987 Just because I was tying different stuff.  I will remove it.

Comment: i think you need `.` to match newline using `(?s)` and also making it lazy..like **[this](http://ideone.com/2iGxGS)**

Comment: also in character class there is no need of alternation..otherwise it will be matched literally..you could have used `[\S\s]*?` though its bit of inefficient

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `.` doesn't match line break characters unless you use the `Singleline` option. Use a set like `\W\w` to match any character or change the option to `Singleline`.

Use `?` after the `*` multiplier to make it non-greedy, otherwise it will match everything and then track back to the last `\f`.

```
string pattern = @"([\W\w]*?)\f";
Match  match = Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

or:

```
string pattern = @"(.*?)\f";
Match  match = Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Comment: First worked but not the second.  One is good enough for me.  Thanks

Comment: I did not change to single line on the second - I get it works also.

Comment: @Paparazzi: My bad, I believed that single line was the default option, but you have to specify the option to make it work that way. I corrected the code above (and verified that it works).

Comment: May I ask which might be most efficient?   The real problem is searching for a pattern but limit it to first page.  Have some really big files and want it to give up and not search 1000+ pages.

Comment: @Paparazzi: There should be very little difference between those two, they basically do the same work. The important thing for performance is the `?` that makes the multiplier non-greedy. WIthout it the `.*` will start by matching the entire text, then it will backtrack by reducing the match by one character at a time until the rest of the pattern matches, which is very inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

As pointed out in comment, I think you need inline `(?s)` modifier or `RegexOptions.Singleline` option to allow `.` to match new lines.

```
string pattern = @"(?s)(.*?)\f";
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/2iGxGS)**

**or**

```
string pattern = @"(.*?)\f";
Match  match = Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/2iGxGS)**

***NOTE*** :- You also need to make your regex lazy using `.*?`

**Solution 2**

If you want, you can use `[\S\s]*?` also, though it will be inefficient.

**SIDE NOTE**

Character class itself acts as an alternation for characters. So using `|` will not act as `OR` but will match `|` literally.

Comment: ALso worked but Guffa came up first and tried it.  Thanks

Comment: @Paparazzi not to offend anyone but you can see the time of my comment..

Comment: OK but I did not see the link.  I was just testing as it came to me.

Comment: @Paparazzi there is nothing to discuss about who answered first..you said the other user came up first..so i just pointed to time of my comment..its your will to accept any answer..period..:)

Comment: I tested your comment but did not did not see the link.   And test tested the comment before.  I gave you a +1.   I am sitting on -4 with what I think is a valid question.